# Avoid converting numbers to dates in plotly

Tags: r, matrix, plotly

I have a matrix that I want to create a heatmap for in plotly. the row names are assays and the colnames are CASRN and they are in this format  "131-55-5"

my matrix looks like this 
[the data matrix for the heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdMcs.png)

for some reason plotly thinks these are dates and converts them to something like March 2000 and gives me an empty plot.

before i convert my data frame to matrix i checked and all columns are factors. 
is there any way I can make sure my numbers wont turn into dates when i plot my matrix?

this is the code i am using for my heatmap

```
plot_ly(x=colnames(dm_new2), y=rownames(dm_new2), z = dm_new2, type = "heatmap") %>%
  layout(margin = list(l=120))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some random data to mimic your dataset. Simply put your matrix in a dataframe. Try this:

```r
set.seed(42)

library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dm_new2 <- matrix(runif(12), nrow = 4, dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:4], c("131-55-5", "113-48-4", "1582-09-8")))

# Put matrix in a dataframe
dm_new2 <- as.data.frame(dm_new2) %>% 
  # rownames to column
  mutate(x = row.names(.)) %>%
  # convert to long format
  pivot_longer(-x, names_to = "y", values_to = "value")

dm_new2 %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~value, type = "heatmap") %>%
  layout(margin = list(l=120))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: It worked. thank you so much. I didnt even think to keep it as data frame! i was keep converting my data to matrix.

Comment: My pleasure. If you want do me a favor: Mark the question as answered. Besides giving me some (extra) credit it shows others with a similar problem that the solution worked and removes the question from the queue of questions still waiting for an answer.